# How to integrate e-commerce or shopping cart into website without using a template?

Tags: php, open-source, e-commerce, shopping-cart, store

An associate of mine wants me to add simple e-commerce functionality into their website.  I have researched the possible solutions to this project for some time now and everything I have seen, including Magnento/osCommerce/BigCommerce/zendcart/etc., all seem to be storefronts and templates you have to style to look like your website.

I do not wish to use the storefronts or templates which may or may not become difficult to style using CSS. I'm looking for some open source PHP solutions I can add into already existing website pages for instance My Bag, Add to Cart, etc; 
I don't necessarily need fancier functions such as coupon redeeming and tax calculators especially if I can extend a current platform on my own.

Is there any shopping cart solution I can use which will not force me into an entirely new template I'd have to further style?

Comment: About the simplest solution I can think of is to display a phone number and have customers call in their order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E-commerce is a lot more complicated than you think. Even something as simple as a persistent shopping cart that allows your user to add a bunch of items takes a fairly significant amount of code. Then there is the whole checkout process and order tracking/fulfilment thing as well. Any true shopping cart is going to include shipping options, payment options, a cart of some sort, a check out process, order generation, etc. If you just want to sell a couple products then just use Paypal or Google Checkout.

Comment: @ Brent Friar Duly noted. I thought there would probably quite a few underlying functions I'd need to keep in mind such as database management for the items, php session cookies etc, and others. I have seen both the PayPal and Google Checkout api and they actually seem pretty reliable. The problem is that their button images will break the designs of the websites I want to use them for. PayPals orange and Google Checkouts blue may not seem like much of a nuisance in a page layout but they will be. If this is all I can use I will move ahead with PayPal full steam

Comment: If you just have a few products, particularly virtual/digital products, then Paypal or Google are great solutions. Paypal even gives the illusion of a true cart with the ability to add multiple products before checking out.

Comment: I have also been getting into PHP lately and have a solid knowledge of C++, assembler, some beginner Java, etc. so I have plans on eventually writing my own shopping cart from the ground up. It will take time, which I don't have for this current project though. Albeit what do you think of this tutorial: http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/building-a-simple-php-shopping-cart ? Drawing from your experience with shopping cart software is it leading me in a solid direction. If not, do you know of any other great tutorials?

Comment: @Brent Friar I have yet to find any tutorials or tips pointing me on how to incorporate security efforts or an actual payment gateway into a shopping cart build from scratch either. You were head on when you mentioned "it's a lot more complicated".. But then again what worthwhile project isn't

Comment: Honestly, you probably won't find a good tutorial. Your best bet is to pick one of the better projects (I would go with Magento) and learn how it works so you can see what they did well and what they didn't. Maybe even try a couple to get a feel for the various hurdles that need to be overcome before you try tackling it yourself. Each of the open source projects has their strengths and weaknesses, learning from those first will make it a lot easier for you.

Comment: BTW - you might also consider building an e-commerce extension for a CMS. Joomla and Drupal are both good frameworks to build on and having that base solves on of the big problems all e-commerce prjects have - handling non-product content. They can all do it, but it's never very elegant or easy for the user.

Answer (score 2):

Jcart can do it, and it seems really basic :

http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/install.php

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged here on SO. Please consider [editing your answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/186599) and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: I guess Che have given perfect answer. It was asked that is there any solution to ecommerce to any website. Che gaves that only. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just code one, its far simple than find out one, configuring it to suit your taste

Comment: You think writing an e-commerce platform would be easier than styling a template in any of the major open source carts???

Comment: Yes I could write one off, debug it in a week.  Think of customizing one and debugging the customization, how long it would take.  Atleast you know where the error is coming from if its your code.

Comment: Any modern cart with a built in templating system takes a day or two at the most to figure out. Debugging CSS is a lot easier than debugging code. Not to mention, any cart written in a week would be very basic.

Comment: this is very true. Writing my own will not be simple but it will allow for the best error tracking on my end and a more streamlined cart by my own design. Thanks

Comment: You even don't need a week, just a couple of days, you can get MvcMusicStore sample, do some hacks, and it surely works. But although it is a very good ecommerce sample, is it good enough to run an ecommerce website seriously?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you could integrate [Moltin](https://molt.in) with your frontend via the [API](http://docs.molt.in). However it's a SaaS platform and it will require a little work to integrate. Should give you flexibility by allowing you to choose which components you use without the templates.